# Reading Parquet files in Dask returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, parquet

I'm trying to replicate [this datashader+parquet+dask+dash](https://dash.gallery/dash-world-cell-towers/) example in order to do something similar with my own data. [Here's the git code.](https://github.com/plotly/dash-world-cell-towers)

The steps to replicate include running the [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/plotly/dash-world-cell-towers/blob/master/notebooks/prepare_cell_data.ipynb) in order to convert the 4 gig csv file into a parquet file. I can run this code without issue, it creates a parquet directory with many ~70 mb sized files in it, but when I try to read the parquet file it returns an empty dataframe (but with the correct columns). So after reading the csv into a dask dataframe and doing some processing I can check the head():

```
ddf.head()
radio   mcc net area    cell    unit    lon lat range   samples changeable  created updated averageSignal   x_3857  y_3857
0   UMTS    262 2   801 86355   0   13.285512   52.522202   1000    7   1   1282569574000000000 1300155341000000000 0   1.478936e+06    6.895103e+06
1   GSM 262 2   801 1795    0   13.276907   52.525714   5716    9   1   1282569574000000000 1300155341000000000 0   1.477979e+06    6.895745e+06
2   GSM 262 2   801 1794    0   13.285064   52.524000   6280    13  1   1282569574000000000 1300796207000000000 0   1.478887e+06    6.895432e+06
3   UMTS    262 2   801 211250  0   13.285446   52.521744   1000    3   1   1282569574000000000 1299466955000000000 0   1.478929e+06    6.895019e+06
4   UMTS    262 2   801 86353   0   13.293457   52.521515   1000    2   1   1282569574000000000 1291380444000000000 0   1.479821e+06    6.894977e+06
```

write it to parquet:

```
# Write parquet file to ../data directory
os.makedirs('./data', exist_ok=True)
parquet_path = './data/cell_towers.parq'
ddf.to_parquet(parquet_path, 
               compression='snappy',  
               write_metadata_file = True)
```

and attempt to read from parquet:

```
ddy = dd.read_parquet('./data/cell_towers.parq' )
```

but it returns and empty dataframe, but with the correct column names:

```
ddy.head(3)
> radio mcc net area    cell    unit    lon lat range   samples changeable  created updated averageSignal   x_3857  y_3857

len(ddy)
> 0
```

This is the first time I'm using dask dataframes and parquet, it *seems* like it should just work but there might be some basic concept I'm missing here.

Small replicable code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddfx = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=['A']), npartitions=2)
parquet_path = './dummy.parq'
ddfx.to_parquet(parquet_path, 
               compression='snappy',  
               write_metadata_file = True)
ddfy = dd.read_parquet('./dummy.parq' ) 
print('Input DDF length: {0} . Output DDF length: {1}'.format(len(ddfx), len(ddfy)))
```

> Input DDF length: 10 . Output DDF length: 0

How can I write a DDF to parquet and then read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the error using `dask=2022.05.2`. There might be some version incompatibility, so I'd recommend installing dask, pandas and fastparquet in a dedicated environment.

Comment: Was running '2021.11.1'. Ran everything in a new environment with '2022.05.2' and it worked as expected... A little frustrating

Comment: Happens fairly often to me also. :)